# laravel 4 input array with mass assignment

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I have this array input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="item[]">

<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="item[]">
```

that can be found more then once within the form.

and i try to use mass assignment but i end up with error:

> preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while
>   replacement is an array

on top of that.. Before i do the mass assignment i want to turn the input array into json so i could store it within one column in the table.

Comment: Can you post your code where you use the Input::all()?

Comment: Model::create(Input::all());

Comment: And can you post your Model?

Comment: The problem is when Model tries to `fill` the attributes and checks if given value is a date, where `preg_replace` is used, which supplied with an array instead of string spits that error. So simply do something like `$input = Input::all(); $input['item'] = json_encode($input['item']);` and then create new record.